# Python: How to extract a string right after another specified string

Tags: python, regex

Let's assume I have two list of strings as follows.

```
lst_1 = ['foo','bar','Invoice No: SME2324-AA']
lst_2 = ['trincas','hotel park','delivery date 12-sept-2019','invoice no: 11245']
```

**Objective:**
I want to extract the invoice number from these two lists.

My Approach so far:

```
lst_3 = [lst_1,lst_2]
txt=[]
for inv_no in lst_3:
    for i in inv_no:
         z = i
         inv = re.search(r'Invoice (\S+) (.+?)',' '.join(z))
         txt.append(inv)
```

When I wanted to see the output i.e. `txt`I am getting as

```
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
```

What I am looking for is

```
['SME2324-AA','11245']
```

What I am missing out here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you do `z=i` and `' '.join(z)`? why not just `inv = re.search(r'Invoice (\S+) (.+?)', i)`? That will get you closer to a solution

Comment: `l3 = [*l1,  *l2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without using `regex`, you can try in this way:

```
lst_3 = lst_1 + lst_2
txt=[]
for i in lst_3:
    if 'invoice' in i.lower():
        txt.append(i.split()[-1])
print (txt)
```

Output:

```
['SME2324-AA', '11245']
```

Comment: Pretty neat, I tried this earlier. Got confused with `[-1]` part. Just to know, why are we using `[-1]`

Comment: `split` separates the string where there is a space. the `[-1]` takes the last of these parts

Answer (score 1):

- First of all, `' '.join` is making every element with white spaces in between.
- Secondly, `(.+?)` stops with first match (i.e. non-greedy) and `r'Invoice...'` is bound to fail with lower-cased `invoice`.
- Thirdly, `append(inv)` will not actually append the matching result; you need to specify group: `if inv: text.append(inv.group(2)`

Fixing all issues:

```
lst_3 = [lst_1,lst_2]
txt=[]
for inv_no in lst_3:
    for i in inv_no:
        z = i
        inv = re.search(r'[Ii]nvoice (\S+) (.+)',z)
        #                      group(1)^    ^group(2)
        if inv:
             txt.append(inv.group(2))
txt
```

Output:

```
['SME2324-AA', '11245']
```

You can make it simpler by using `re.findall` with `re.IGNORECASE`:

```
import re

res = []
for i in lst_1 + lst_2:
    res.extend(re.findall('invoice no: (.+)', i, re.IGNORECASE))
res
```

Output:

```
['SME2324-AA', '11245']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try joining your lists together to form a single string, then using `re.findall` to find all invoice numbers:

```
lst_1 = ['foo','bar','Invoice No: SME2324-AA']
lst_2 = ['trincas','hotel park','delivery date 12-sept-2019','invoice no: 11245']
lst_all = lst_1 + lst_2
inp = " ".join(lst_all)
invoices = re.findall(r'\binvoice no: (\S+)', inp, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(invoices)
```

This prints:

```
['SME2324-AA', '11245']
```

Comment: This only prints the first invoice number i.e. SME2324-AA

Comment: @pythondumb No, it prints _every_ invoice number contained in your two lists.  Maybe you need to reload your page?